# app.router deprecated message even after app.use(app.router) removed

Tags: node.js, lambda

I have an app that I'm trying to make into an API with lambda and claudia. I'm getting 'Error: 'app.router' is deprecated' even after I remove the line app.use(app.router) which is what the docs say: https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

here is my server.js code: (i removed any adding of paths and it still gives me that error)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('assets'));

app.use(enableCors);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error',   {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

function enableCors(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
}

module.exports = app;
```

Could this have something to do with caching? Are there any other methods that I need to update in order to satisfy the 'app.router deprecated' call?

Comment: There is also the possibility that the error is coming from one of the modules your using - e.g it's using the version of a module for express 3.x instead of 4.x

Comment: thanks, Keith! so, i moved everything to a new app that doesn't have node_modules dir with all the modules just the clauida-api and that doesn't give me the errors. I think you are right, however, it must be some other file. Though a global search on app.router doesn't come up with anything except in the node_modules/express where the error is defined.